# How Can I Insert A Value With Javascript (or PHP) Into a Form Depending On Visitor Referral

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, google-analytics, visitors

I'm not sure if the way to do this is check Google Analytics cookies or otherwise track where a user came to my site from. Basically I have a form with a hidden field `code="XY1"` Now I need to be able to insert a different preset code for say people who came from Facebook, so the script would have to check where the visitor came from and then assign a code XF1 to any from FB, and a code XT1 to any from Twitter, etc.

Would something like this PHP work for the capture?:

```
$referringPage = parse_url( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
if ( stristr( $referringPage['host'], 'facebook.com' ) )
```

Or this JS

```
var ref = document.referrer;

if (!ref.indexOf("facebook.com") != -1) {
  document.write(...)
}
```

I'm not sure what is the best way to do it and what kind of methods can reliably check the source of a visitor, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: HTTP_REFERER is browser set, and very unreliable

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, but it's not guaranteed to be accurate, or even present. Not all browsers will necessarily set it, and some allow you to set it yourself. Google cookies won't contain any site history, and you can't examine the browser history, so there's no guaranteed way to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can  try this option using jquery $.test() method.

```
$(function(){
    var referer=document.referrer,  //option 1  
    //referer="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];?>",//optional 2
    XFB=/facebook.com/g,
    XFT=/twitter.com/g,
    checkF1=XFB.test(referer),
    checkF2=XFT.test(referer);
if(checkF1){
    var code= "XF1";
  $('#hiddenInput').attr('value','ref:  '+referer)

}
else if(checkF2){
    var code= "XT1";
 $('#hiddenInput').attr('value','ref:  '+referer)
}
});
```

Comment: This is interesting, is document.referrer about as accurate as http_referer in PHP ? Also, this would not track anything past the original landing page correct? How should I go about incorporating a cookie here so the script could work if the visitor clicks around on the site before going to the form?

Comment: Yes both the php and and javascript work fine. To track all pages with script you will want to have it included in all your pages. You dont have to have a form .You save your data in a .txt file or in a database using ajax. So let say on each page you have something like this. see My next comments...............

Comment: $(function(){
    localStorage.location=document.location;
    localStorage.referrer=document.referrer;
    //as you know 'localStorage' is the same $_SESSION in php        
    var 
    location=localStorage.location,
    referrer=localStorage.referrer,    
    XFB=/facebook.com/g,
    XFT=/twitter.com/g,
    checkF1=XFB.test(referrer),
    checkF2=XFT.test(referrer);
    
    if(checkF1){var code= "XF1";}
    
else if(checkF2){var code= "XT1";}    
//Ajax goes here see next comment
    
   //alert(location+referrer); 
   //just for a test make sure ajax url is valid 
});

Comment: $.post("addTotxtFileOrDataBase.php",                
  {code:code,location:location,referrer:referrer;},
  function(data){
      //do whatever or nothing
  } );// end ajax here